# younger older brother

Tags: adjectives

A girl is introducing her family members one by one to her nine month old sister, Charlie. Walking to Dave, she says,

> that's your younger older brother, Dave.

Dave is the youngest kid except Charlie in the family.

What does *younger older* mean?

Comment: Seems an unnatural way to talk to a baby. Wouldn't she just call them 'big brothers'? The child will come to understand their relative ages as she grows up.

Comment: She's recording a video for the baby to watch when  she grows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *younger older brother* should be parsed as *younger (older brother)*, not *(younger older) brother*. Dave is Charlie's older brother, but he is younger than any of the other older brothers. The sister could also have called Dave Charlie's *youngest older brother*. (This is probably what I would call Dave. I would probably only refer to Dave as the *younger older brother* if I were comparing him to one other brother. For example, "Between Dave and James, Dave is the younger older brother.")

Comment: Thank you very much. How would you call James? older older brother?

Comment: Eldest brother?